# using outdated version of MyAssembley.XmlSerializers.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934411/what-is-myassembly-xmlserializers-dll-generated-for) that my project has the MyAssembley.XmlSerializers.dll file created because I have "Generate serialization assembly" set to auto in my project properties.

I am deploying the class library to a server, and was wondering what would happen:

- If I only deploy MyAssembley.dll without the MyAssembley.XmlSerializers.dll
  (what I think is that the .NET runtime will just generate it on the fly)

If I already have deployed both dll's once.

- and I make a change to MyAssembley.dll (I assume MyAssembley.XmlSerializers.dll would also change) but I only end up deploying the MyAssembley.dll. Therefore end up with MyAssembley.dll (newest version) and MyAssembley.XmlSerializers.dll (old version) [taking me into question 1 maybe ?]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid errors, just turn off the serialization. Therefore there will be no problem with Assembly Version of MyAssembly.XMLSerializers.dll

Unless you have a big project that is using HUGE amounts of memory, you can safely turn the serialization off.

Comment: How can serialization be turned off?